# what problem does the serialization proxy pattern solves that the serialization pattern doesn't solve?

Tags: c#, java, vb.net, serialization, proxy

I need to be able to serialize a class into a string, and I know of 2 patterns:

1. (normal) Serialization pattern
2. Proxy Serialization pattern

I've read [this blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20110504033130/http://lingpipe-blog.com/2009/08/10/serializing-immutable-singletons-serialization-proxy/) (the only website in google that talks about the proxy-serialization pattern) and still cant find the **advantage** or **benefit** of using this pattern. Could someone explain what exactly is the proxy serialization pattern, or rather exactly what problem does the proxy-serialization pattern solves that the normal-serialization pattern doesn't solve?

Answer (score 1):

Default serialization:

- Creates multiple instances of classes supposed to be singletons on deserialization
- Supposedly has issues with changed in-the-fly deserialized objects (huh?)

Second point is arguable. Who has changed the data of the bytestream? If it could happen we have a bigger issue than deserialization: security. Signed/encrypted streams would solve the serialization issue too.

First one is real one. Serialize the same singleton a few time, deserialize on the other side, and oops! you have multiple singletons (multitones?). That problem though is IMHO easier solved by making a singleton out of Enum, then JVM will enforce the single instance itself.

**UPDATE**

As was pointed out by Steve B, the blog poster perhaps misunderstood/misrepresented what did he read. Instead of "serialize, tweak bytes, then deserialize" one should read "serialize, deploy new version of the class, deserialize". Yes, this is known problem, and Externalizable interface allows one to solve it neatly by taking a full control over the class serialization, so even the later version of the class can deserialize own data from a stream created by a previous versions (if it possible at all).

Comment: The issues with changed-on-the-fly objects - if you change the objects signature (basically anything that would give you a different result with serialver) your serialization becomes incompatible with any previously serialized objects. Moving the serialization behavior into a separate object insulates you somewhat from that (until, of course, your proxies become incompatible).

Comment: This is understood. The article though says: "The problem is that you can serialize an instance, tweak the bytes representing numbers, then deserialize." This is not the same problem (not version incompatibility).

Comment: i'm not specifically talking about serializing a singleton. i'm just serializing normal instances..